# When is det$(I-A^T)=-\text{det}(A-I)$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra

When det$(I-A^T)=-\text{det}(A-I)$ is true? Is this true in general or only for $A \in \text{SO}\setminus \{I\}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$det(A-I)=(-1)^ndet(I-A^T)$$

So the equation is valid for either:

- $n$ is odd or
- $det(A-I)$ is 0

Answer (score 3):

$$\det(A-I)=\det((A-I)^T)=\det(A^T-I)=\det(-(I-A^T))=(-1)^n\det(I-A^T)$$

Answer (score 1):

This is true for any square matrix of odd size, since it is just $$\det (B)=\det(B^T)=-\det(-B^T)$$ for $B=I-A^T$.